# Jssor - arrow key navigation

Tags: jssor

Can I use jssor slider along with fullPage slider:
http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#secondPage/1

Can I use up/down arrow keys for the navigation when drag orientation is set to vertical (2) ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example, http://www.jssor.com/testcase/full-screen-slider-new-api.source.html

And you can call $Prev, $Next api when you detect key press of up/down.

```
//call $Prev while 'up' keypress event fires
jssor_slider1.$Prev();

//call $Next while 'down' keypress event fires
jssor_slider1.$Next();
```

Comment: Hi, how to reference the slider if slider is initialized in external js